# Creating a KeyValuePair list by iterating over an array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an array like this:

```
Foo[] objects;
```

I want a list of `KeyValuePair<Foo, float>` from `objects`.
The `float` value for first element is `0.2f` and it should be incremented per elements. It means float value for first element is 0.2 and for third element is 0.6.

The for loop to accomplish this:

```
float value = 0.2f;
foreach(Foo f in objects)
{
   myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<Foo,float>(f, value));
   value += 0.2f
}
```

I just wondering is there any way to do it with LINQ and lambda expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var myList = objects
    .Select((f, index) =>  new KeyValuePair<Foo, float>(f, (index + 1) * 0.2f))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't index the 2nd param and f in first like so: `var myList = objects.Select((f, i) => new KeyValuePair<Foo, float>(f, (i + 1)*0.2f));`  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Did you try this code? It doesn't compile. And the `index` & `f` parameters are around the wrong way. And it doesn't actually produce a list - just an enumerable.

Comment: My mistake. I stubbed it out quick in LinqPad but used a `List<int>` and misinterpreted the parameter description. I have updated my answer

Comment: @DLeh - It still doesn't compile.

Comment: @ham3d did you check the updated version? i had the lambda switched at first

Comment: @DLeh - Works now. Those pesky missing parenthesis are killers. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the point, you could change the start `value`, and have a one line:

```
float value = 0.0f;
myList.AddRange(objects.Select(f => 
    new KeyValuePair<Foo,float>(f, value += 0.2f)));
```

Comment: I like the index approach better since less side effect, but this works as well.

Answer (score 0):

And using Dictionary (which is also a KeyValuePair)

```
public void FooToLinq()
{
    Foo[] objs = { new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo() };
    float value = 0.2f;
    var dictionary = objs.ToDictionary(x => x, x => value += 0.2f);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Foo, float> pair in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair);
    }
}
```

and the output is (I didn't override the to string, so it is namespace.class+nestedClass)

```
[StackOverflowTests.UnitTests+Foo, 0.4]
[StackOverflowTests.UnitTests+Foo, 0.6]
[StackOverflowTests.UnitTests+Foo, 0.8]
```

And to make it a list you have a few options

```
myList = objs.ToDictionary(x => x, x => value += 0.2f).ToList();

//or to split the line up a little
var dictionary = objs.ToDictionary(x => x, x => value += 0.4f);
myList = dictionary.ToList();//option 2
myList.AddRange(dictionary);//option 3
```

either way you get the desired results. As pointed out by others though if you want to ensure that the index is tied to a specific index then use the select approach.

Comment: Why the down vote? This uses the LINQ extension methods, and creates a KeyValue pair as the OP wants. What is wrong about it?

Comment: incrementing a value in a lambda is unsafe.

Comment: Well the OP asked for a list of key value pairs which would allow for duplicate keys, where as a dictionary would not.

Comment: @Dleh how is it unsafe? Pardon my ignorance on this subject, but if there is a specific need to have the value tied to a specific instance of the class then I agree this is the wrong approach.

Comment: I don't want a  Dictionary, I specifically wrote "I want a list of KeyValuePair<Foo, float>"

Answer (score -1):

The shortest answer is following

```
var myDictionary= objects.Select((value, index) => new { index, value })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.value, x => (x.index + 1) * .2f);
```

and if a list is required just call `.ToList`

```
var myList = myDictionary.ToList();
```

Comment: It's actually longer by 7 characters than DLeh's answer - so it's not shortest. And it also relies on the internal implementation of `.ToDictionary(...).ToList()` to return the elements in the order required by the OP - there's no guarantee that that would happen.

Comment: The use of an intermediate dictionary would not allow for duplicate keys where as the OP's current code does.

Comment: @juharr that means the the instances would have to be the same for that, or Equalty would have to overriden.

Comment: @RobertSnyder Yes, and we have no information about either from this question.  I was just pointing out a potential issue with this answer.